# Как проверить текстовый редактор на строку при типе StringVar()?

Tags: python

Есть переменная `email = StringVar()` которая передает введенный логин, хочу проверить через `open file` имеется ли введенный логин уже в текстовом редакторе Users.txt,но компилятор пишет, что не может прочитать при типе данных `StringVar()`, вопрос в том ,что как можно преобразовать переменную `email` ,чтобы `open file` смог прочитать ее .. И естественно если там имеется строка ,который ввел пользователь в `Entry` ,то выдастся предупреждение

```
email = tk.StringVar()

email_entry = ttk.Entry(signin, textvariable=email)

file = open('C://Users.txt', 'r')
datafile = file.readlines()
for line in datafile:
    if email.get() in line:
      return True
```

Ошибка компилятора:

```
datafile = file.readlines()
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable
```

Comment: Так у вас ошибка, что скорее всего у скрипта нет прав читать этот файл. Или может файл открыт в редакторе и редактор не даёт его никому читать.

Comment: Нет ,скорее всего проблема в самой переменной типа StringVar() потому что когда я делал это через обычный string input,проблем не возникало ,оно сейчас ругается на то ,что Entry берется через тип StringVar()

Comment: Но ведь ошибка вообще никак не связана с этим кодом и этой переменной

Comment: раз так думаете напишите как исправить тогда.. Я говорю что это из за переменной StringVar()